# Integrating a Stored Procedure in UnitOfWork/Repository pattern

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I've got an application with MVC and Entity Framework. The application uses Unit of Work and Repository patterns for CRUD operations. But I've got to add now a couple of stored procedures that already exist in database. One of them just retrieves data from one of the entities (this is achieved at this moment by the repository pattern) but adds an extra column to the final result, created and populated in the stored procedure.

I want to integrate the use of these stored procedures into my architecture. I've tried to add the stored procedures to my model, map it to the class and use it, but as I have to add an extra column to this entity in the model, I get an error that this field is not mapped.

Should I use my repository for this particular entity just for Add/Edit/Delete and create another entity with the extra field that will be used for just the Get action using the stored procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I use my repository for this particular entity just for Add/Edit/Delete and create another entity with the extra field that will be used for just the Get action using the stored procedure

Depends on the use case? Sounds like it's used for a different case and if so I would create a new entity for it.

Comment: Thanks jgauffin, that's what I did.